# replacement for Autofac.Integration.Web.Mvc (upgrading from autofac 2.3 to 2.6)

Tags: autofac

Autofac.Integration.Web.Mvc dll in autofac version 2.3.2.632 had a class AutofacControllerFactory defined as

```
 public class AutofacControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        public AutofacControllerFactory(IContainerProvider containerProvider);

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext context, Type controllerType);
        public override void ReleaseController(IController controller);
    }
```

The latest version of autofac (2.6.3.862) doesn't have Autofac.Integration.Web.Mvc, but instead is has 
Autofac.Integration.Mvc. However this dll doesnot have a AutofacControllerFactory class. The dll Autofac.Integration.Mvc has a class called AutofacDependencyResolver  defined as

```
public class AutofacDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    public AutofacDependencyResolver(ILifetimeScope container);
    public AutofacDependencyResolver(ILifetimeScope container, Action<ContainerBuilder> configurationAction);
    public AutofacDependencyResolver(ILifetimeScope container, ILifetimeScopeProvider lifetimeScopeProvider);
    public AutofacDependencyResolver(ILifetimeScope container, ILifetimeScopeProvider lifetimeScopeProvider, Action<ContainerBuilder> configurationAction);

    public ILifetimeScope ApplicationContainer { get; }
    public static AutofacDependencyResolver Current { get; }
    public ILifetimeScope RequestLifetimeScope { get; }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType);
    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType);
}
```

**What is the replacement for AutofacControllerFactory in the latest version of Autofac?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no replacement for `AutofacControllerFactory`. Instead, use the `DependencyResolver`.

[The Autofac wiki has documentation on the new way to integrate with later versions of ASP.NET MVC.](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration) That wiki page includes a link to a sample application where you can see real working code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is from changes to the API of MVC through the versions. In MVC 3/4, believe all you need to put in your `Application_Start` is:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```